# What is the standard Woocommerce Return URL for Paypal?

Tags: paypal, woocommerce

I noticed that when I order on my woocommerce site with Paypal that I'm not returned automatically to the website. I found where to set this option on my Paypal profile, but I have to enter a return URL. Is there a standard return URL?

Answer (score 10):

RETURN URL would be >>>> yoursite.com/checkout/order-received/

You can read up more about the settings from this page.
http://wphow.org/setup-paypal-to-accept-credit-cards/

Answer (score 6):

It should be: **YourDomain**/checkout/order-received/

You can find all the information with the latest update on this link:

[How to set PayPal with Woo-commerce + Return URL](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/paypal-standard/)

I had the same question and this solved my issue.

And Also to make it easy without following the link you need to follow this steps:

**You can set up auto-return in your PayPal account, which will take customers to a receipt page. For example, use the following URL and replace YourDomain with your own URL:**

**YourDomain**/checkout/order-received/

Add **?utm_nooverride=1** to the end of your URL to ensure that transactions (i.e., conversions) are credited to the original traffic source, rather than PayPal.

So the full link should look like something like this:
**YourDomain**/checkout/order-received/**?utm_nooverride=1**

Now, 
1-Go to your PayPal account >> Profile Tab >> Account Setting >> My selling tools >> Website preferences and Click update on the right side.
2-You will find Return URL: text field you need to updated it with the link above.

Image attached.[image: PayPal Return URL]

I hope this will help

Comment: How to setup 1 PayPal account with multiple websites?

Answer (score 1):

/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/classes/gateways/paypal/class-wc-gateway-paypal.php is where the PayPal Standard request is dynamically generated.  Within that it's making a call to [get_return_url()](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Payment_Gateway.html#49-73) to generate the return URL.

So, it's being dynamically generated based on order data and SSL settings on the site.  It's basing it off your "thanks" page, though, so you could just set the Auto-Return setting in your PayPal profile to whatever that URL is as a basic setting.  The return URL getting included in the payment requests should override that anyway.

Comment: There is a problem if you are using 1 PayPal address with multiple websites.

Comment: If you use our PayPal for WooCommerce plugin instead of PayPal Standard that comes with Woo, then all these issues would go away.  :)  

https://www.angelleye.com/product/woocommerce-paypal-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress > WooCommerce > settings > Checkout > PayPal

Uncheck or turn off the "Use form submission method" option. With the option disabled this all works fine.

Comment: I do not see this option anywhere "Use form submission method"

Answer (score 0):

On a French install of WordPress/WooCommerce, the checkout page is named "commande".
Also, one can change the WooCommerce checkout endpoints (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-endpoints-2-1/).

Maybe a more generic answer to this URL question would be

*YourDomain/YourCheckoutPageName/YourWooCommerceCheckoutEndpoint/?utm_nooverride=1*

(The utm_nooverride part is described in Tariq Ahmed's answer.)

The default *YourDomain/checkout/order-received/?utm_nooverride=1* could for instance be *YourDomain/commande/commande-recue/?utm_nooverride=1*.

I think. :)